# Parsing vCards on web pages into a MySQL DB

Tags: php, mysql, html-parsing, vcf-vcard, hcard

I have a client who is using a separate vCard on a separate page.  These are being pasted into a wordpress text field.   (Not the most efficient way to maintain a list of people, but I won't editorialize after the fact.) My mission is to write something to parse through all the addresses in the vCards and to dump the information into a central database.  This would allow all the disparate pages to become addresses replete with lat and lng coordinates from google and display a lovely front page with pins galore.
This page would show all the vcards from the rest of the pages of the site.

Oh, this is an example, sanitized, of a vcard on the site, in reality it would be surrounded by a lot of dubious HTML code:

```
<div class="vcard">
<span class="fn org">XYZ Org Name</span><br />
<span class="url">http://www.someurl.com/</span>
<div class="adr"><span class="street-address">1234 Main Ave</span><br />
<span class="locality">Chicago</span><br />
<span class="region">IL</span><br /><span class="postal-code">60647</span></div>
</div>
```

Now, each page has one of these, and to spider through the entire site, and collect them into an array is a bit out of my league.  I can handle dumping them into a database, using PHP and mySQL.
Any and all advice would be welcome!
EDIT: Not sure how important this is, but I am pulling the data from a different server.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for HTML parsers. [Here](http://docs.python.org/library/htmlparser.html) is HTML parsing module for python

You need to parse the relevant data out of all the HTML files and then do whatever with it.

I have not tried any php html parsers to recommend any but since you are working on a webserver I'm hoping it has perl?  Take a look at [perl html parsers](http://www.cse.iitm.ac.in/~shonima/project/CSDProject/codes/tpj0501-0003.html).

#this snippet will get contents of organization name

```
 sub start {
      my ($self, $tag, $attr, $attrseq, $origtext) = @_;

      if ($tag =~ /^span$/i && $attr->{'class'} =~ /^fn org$/i) {
          # see if we find <span class="fn org"
          push (@org_names, $origtext);
      } 
  }
```

now you have `@org_names` array that contains all organization names.

Comment: I can't run Python on my server.

Answer (score 0):

Try the DOMDocument class' [loadHTML method](http://us.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php).  Then you can use DOMDocument methods to select the nodes, attributes and values you want.  Or if you're familiar with XPath, you can also instantiate a [DOMXPath](http://us.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) object to query against the loaded DOMDocument to select the desired data.